# Changing a second class on hover class one

Tags: html, css

I want to change two classes on hover an `<a>` element.  What am I doing wrong?

```css
/*main element on hover*/

.myel>div a.nav-item.nav-link:hover {
  color: blue;
}

/*second element which should changed too*/

.myel>div a.nav-item.nav-link:hover>.myel>div a.nav-item.nav-link i {
  color: red;
}

/*also*/

.myel>div a.nav-item.nav-link:hover .myel>div a.nav-item.nav-link i {
  color: red;
}

/*also*/

.myel>div a.nav-item.nav-link:hover div a.nav-item.nav-link i {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<nav class="myel">
  <div class="nav nav-tabs nav-fill" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
    <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">
      <i class="fas fa-clipboard-check">icon</i>
      <span>text</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Please post your HTML as well. We need a [mcve]

Comment: i've add the html part, sorry

Comment: The `>` means "direct child element of" and you've got some selectors using it incorrectly for what your HTML is.  I think you meant to add some commas in there instead of spaces or the `>` selector in a few places

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You weren't a million miles away. It's simpler than you think...

```css
.myel > div a.nav-item.nav-link {
    color: pink;
}

.myel > div a.nav-item.nav-link:hover {
    color:blue;
}

.myel > div a.nav-item.nav-link:hover > i {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<nav class="myel">
    <div class="nav nav-tabs nav-fill" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">
            <i class="fas fa-clipboard-check">I</i>
            <span>text</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2):

As a side note: You should read about `CSS Selectors` a bit more.

You cannot go back to parent, you have to continue from where you are.

in this case, when

`.myel > div a.nav-item.nav-link:hover` is selected, if you want to choose another element from here, you can either go to sibling or children

which means you can add `> i` to the end and you will choose the child `i` element in case `.nav-link` is being hovered

```css
/*main element on hover*/
.myel > div a.nav-item.nav-link:hover {
    color:blue;
}

/*second element which should changed too*/
.myel > div a.nav-item.nav-link:hover > i{
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<nav class="myel">
    <div class="nav nav-tabs nav-fill" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">
            <i class="fas fa-clipboard-check">icon</i>
            <span>text</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</nav>
```